# function passed as React prop is not appearing in called child

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React component render method defined as below, which includes passing a prop called onExchangeSelect into the ExchangeList component.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList
            exchanges={this.state.exchanges} selected={this.state.selectedExchange}
            onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange})}
        />
        <ExchangeDetail exchange={this.state.selectedExchange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Then, in the ExchangeList constructor, when I console.log this.props, there is not a prop called onExchangeSelect which I can call and th.

The intent is to pass a callback function from the top level component to a child component, to be called by the child so as to affect the state of the parent component. The entire top-level class is below:

```
class ExchangeContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exchanges:[
        {
          name:"binance",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        },
        {
          name:"bittrex",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      ],
      selectedExchange:"binance"
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList
            exchanges={this.state.exchanges} selected={this.state.selectedExchange}
            onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange})}
        />
        <ExchangeDetail exchange={this.state.selectedExchange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why is the function not available as a prop in the child component? (below):

```
class ExchangeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };

    console.log('This props ' + JSON.stringify(this.props))
  }

  render() {
    console.log("EL: " + JSON.stringify(this.props))

      const ExItemList = this.props.exchanges.map((exchange) => {
        return  <ExchangeListItem key={exchange.name} exchange={exchange}
                                  onExchangeSelect={this.props.onExchangeSelect}/>
      });


    return (
      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group bg-light" >
        {ExItemList}
      </ul>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `this.props` by `props` in the constructor. What do you see?

Comment: I see two out of the three props: "exchanges" and "selected"

Comment: Of course, `JSON.stringify` excludes functions! Not seeing it does not mean it's not there. Try and log `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(props)` instead.

Comment: A function can't be serialized in a JSON. Try this `console.log('This props' + props)`, it'll show all the three props.

Answer (score 0):

i would inspect them in dev tools instead of console.log..place break point and check in chrome dev tool.. onExchangeSelect should be available as part of props in child component..

Answer (score 0):

the [offical docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) says you should bind the method to a property inside the constructor function. you can play around on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-waterfall-xlj2i?file=/src/App.js:534-964) for the code below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: "binance",
          url: "https://bittrex.com"
        },
        {
          name: "bittrex",
          url: "https://bittrex.com"
        }
      ],
      selectedExchange: "binance"
    };
    // bind "this" to handleOnExchange method
    this.handleOnExchange = this.handleOnExchange.bind(this);
  }
  // method to be bound
  handleOnExchange (data) {
    this.setState({selectedExchange: data})
  }

  render() {
    const ExchangeList = props => <div />;
    const ExchangeDetail = props => <div />;
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList
          exchanges={this.state.exchanges}
          selected={this.state.selectedExchange}
          // pass the method to a child property (onExchangeSelect)
          onExchangeSelect={this.handleOnExchange}
        />
        <ExchangeDetail selectedExchange={this.state.selectedExchange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

to use it inside a (class-based) child component, call the method with an arg like this:

```
this.props.onExchangeSelect(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it can't see it is because you are looking for it in the wrong place. You are looping through the **"exchange"** props to create a new component so when you reference **"this.props.onExchangeSelect"**, you are not referring the the props passed to the class as you expected but to the **exchange object** through which you are looping.

To remedy this, consider rewriting the ExchangeContainer component like so:

```
     class ExchangeContainer extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {
          exchanges:[
            {
              name:"binance",
              url:"https://bittrex.com"
            },
            {
              name:"bittrex",
              url:"https://bittrex.com"
            }
          ],
          selectedExchange:"binance"
     };

  }

    setSelectedExchange = (selectedExchange) =>{
        this.setState({selectedExchange})
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList
            exchanges={this.state.exchanges} selected={this.state.selectedExchange}
            onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => setSelectedExchange(selectedExchange)}
        />
        <ExchangeDetail exchange={this.state.selectedExchange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the ExchangeList component like so:

```
    class ExchangeList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
       super(props);

         this.state = {
         };

       }

  render() {
    console.log("EL: " + JSON.stringify(this.props));

      const {exchanges, selected, onExchangeSelect} = this.props;

      const ExItemList = exchanges.map((exchange) => {
        return  <ExchangeListItem key={exchange.name} exchange={exchange}
                                  onExchangeSelect={onExchangeSelect}/>
      });


    return (
      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group bg-light" >
        {ExItemList}
      </ul>

    );
  }
}
```